# Иероглифы в sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

Я не знаю связано это или нет, но я только что удалил и заново установит Python 3.7. После чего на любой запрос в Sublime text 3 он мне выдает иероглифы. Как это исправить?

[image]

Comment: Переходи на **PyCharm**. `https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/`.
Как по многим мнениям, он самый лучший!

Comment: Мне кажется, что он слишком много оперативки ест у меня и немного подглючивает, в отличие от ST3

Comment: Нормально он оперативки жрет.И имеет бесплатную версию , а ST нет.
Продуткы jetbrains имеют довольно умеренные требования 
к машине.(это те не vs)

Comment: Скорее всего некорректно установлен Python. Проверь в командной сроке windows команду python. Если не выдаёт никакой версии, переустанови python с параметром PATH(что-то там) в начале установки.